# Reversing the Order Using Divide and Conquer

Tags: java, divide-and-conquer

I have an assignment where basically I am reversing the order of a generic object array, and I have to use divide and conquer. I am very confused on how to accomplish this with divide and conquer, and I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction, as I don't completely understand the concept in terms of coding it out.

Comment: I'm confused too, as I don't know what your professor means by "divide and conquer".  To me, it means breaking up the problem into smaller and smaller pieces until you can easily code each piece.  The easiest way to reverse an array is to create a new array and copy the elements from the original array to the new array.

Comment: How about you do your own **research**, e.g. a *web search* for the title of your question leads to answers: [`Reversing the Order Using Divide and Conquer`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Reversing+the+Order+Using+Divide+and+Conquer)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc *Hint (from duplicate answer):* "Any problem that is solved with a **recursive** algorithm follows the **Divide and Conquer** paradigm."